# react-native-firebase crashlytics enable Android NDK reports

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native-firebase, crashlytics-android

I'm working on app which uses many external modules. Crashlytics sometimes sends strange debug info - it shows error on empty string in my code. 
I'm using 'react-native-firebase-crashlytics' module with 'enableNdk true'. But I've found official tutorial how to enable android NDK - [Get Android NDK crash reports with the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports-new-sdk)

I looked at firebase-crashlytics NDK implementation and it works different way. From 'build.gradle' file:

```
// don't use firebase bom here as crashlytics-ndk is not included in the bom, trying to partially use bom here fails
  implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("firebase", "crashlytics")}"
  // ndk not in Firebase BoM
  implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("firebase", "crashlyticsNdk")}"
```

Is it make sense to use NDK integration from official firebase documentation instead of react-native crahslytics with enabled `crashlytics {enableNdk true}` ?